# How do I get the touchpad working on an ASUS N551V?

Tags: grub2, touchpad, asus

I have ASUS N551V with fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 and my touchpad is not working.

I tried a few solutions from Internet, but no success.

For example, several solutions I have tried:

- editing this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"` in `/etc/default/grub`
- using **dconf Editor**, where the touchpad is enabled

Can someone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: My biggest problem on N551 is: I couldn't install ubuntu16.04 onto it.